# Regex URL extract without www

Tags: php, regex

I have this `/href *= *[\'"]\Khttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com[^\'"]+/` expression to extract twitter-urls. It works great for all urls starting with **www**, but not if **www** is missing. What do I have to change this line to, in order to have both links (with and without www) fetched with RegEx?

```
<a href="//www.twitter.com/anything">LINK1</a>
<a href="//twitter.com/anything">LINK2</a>
```

Thanks for your help!

Yes, I know there are some posts containing that issue and showing solutions to that, but none of them really helped me solve this.

Answer (score 3):

`www` is not the problem. As you can see, your pattern contains `https?`, you have to make it optional:

```
href *= *[\'"]\K(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com[^\'"]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/z5VRSI/1).